How do I configure the Dev Server to work with PHP in 2024?
Can someone help me configure the Dev-server to work with PHP in 2024?
I've found plenty of examples online, but most seem to be for older versions of Webpack. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!
I've set up a VirtualHost in Apache using XAMPP on my local machine:
<VirtualHost *:80>
      DocumentRoot "C:\Users\44\Desktop\portfolio"
      ServerName portfolio.localhost
      <Directory "C:\Users\44\Desktop\portfolio">
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
      </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

Webpack devServer config:
devServer: {   
    compress: true,   
    port: 8080,            
    proxy: [
        {
            '/api': {
                target: 'http://portfolio.localhost:80',
                changeOrigin: true,
                secure: false,
            },

            devMiddleware: {
                    writeToDisk: true,
            },
        }
    ]
},

"webpack": "^5.93.0"
"webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.0"

The idea is that when I access: http://localhost:8080 (Webpack Dev Server), it should proxy to http://portfolio.localhost:80/ (Apache local vhost). However, this isn't happening. When I access http://localhost:8080/index.html and try to click on a .php link, the file just gets downloaded instead of being executed.
Here’s what my entire webpack.dev.js file looks like: webpack.dev.js

A search for "apache php downloads file" turns up many questions here already, have you been through those?

This question is similar to: Apache is downloading php files instead of displaying them. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You set up the proxy to Apache on "/api", but you are accessing "/".

ServerName poetfolio... has a typo.

You can create your own local Docker Dev server. You can take a PHP image and a Node.js image from DockerHub and run them in Docker Compose. This is the most correct way in 2024.

Why is that the "most correct way"? Who had the final vote in this decision?
